# jQuery's draggable() function isn't working

Tags: jquery, html, css, draggable

Here's a JSFiddle I have: http://jsfiddle.net/o5tupLcb/.

My problem is, why isn't the div dragging? Even if I make $(".drag").draggable(); its own statement outside of the switch statements, it doesn't work.

Here's some jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".drag").mousedown(function(e) {
        switch (e.which) {
        case 1:
            $(this).toggleClass("mousedown");
            $(this).draggable(); /* This probably shouldn't be here */
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    });

    $(".drag").mouseup(function(e) {
        switch (e.which) {
        case 1:
            $(this).toggleClass("mousedown");
            $(this).draggable(); /* This probably shouldn't be here */
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    });
});
```

Please note that I already tried to import jQuery UI and nothing happened.

Edit: Turns out I was importing the wrong thing. Also, the draggable() function works better when I take it out of the switch statements and just put it below.

Comment: **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**. You didn't include jQuery UI, let alone jQuery

Comment: I tried importing that in the HTML head and it still didn't word.

Comment: You're probably right. You're trying to reinvent draggability and also use jQuery UI's. Just use `$("selector").draggable()` to make it draggable - no need to bind events and use your logic

Comment: And you can't **just** include jQuery UI. You have to include jQuery **and then** jQuery UI.

Comment: Btw, i have no idea why you've linked to local files such as `style.css`, `script.js` etc in a fiddle...

Comment: I did that because I just copy-pasted it from Notepad++.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaned up your code on jsfiddle, included jQuery and jQuery UI.  Also changed html to be only:

```
<div class="drag">Hello</div>
```

Now works (after first click).  This makes sense since the event is fired after you first click (and again after you release).

http://jsfiddle.net/o5tupLcb/1/

Comment: Wow, thanks! Now I only have to edit the toggleClass thingies because the mousedown CSS class is alternating in an undesirable manner.

Comment: Yep, you were pretty much there.  Was just the way you displayed it in jsfiddle.  Only put in the content inside the body tags, not the body tags themselves.  Check external resources for jQuery UI and frameworks up the top for jQuery.

Comment: Also, since you know which is click (mousedown) and which is release(mouseup) consider using addClass and removeClass.  More specific and can help resolve issues that may arise from "lag".

Comment: If this is resolved, please mark a correct answer (click the tick up and left).